# Definition of quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals

I have a question about the definition of quotient ring (I mean a commutative ring  case) .

Let $(a+I)$ be a coset of $R$ and $(b+I)$ be another left coset of $R$.

Then the multiplication in the quotient ring is defined as

$(a+I)(b+I)=(ab+I)$

However, if we consider the setwise product of $(a+I)$ and $(b+I)$ we know that their product is just a subset of a fixed coset of $I$. Then why should I believe the multiplication in the quotient ring is well-defined?

Comment: Why are you considering their setwise product?

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446492/what-does-defining-multiplication-in-quotient-rings-actually-mean) for more details. Egreg's answer shows why you "should believe" that it is well-defined.

Comment: Doubting that "multiplication in the quotient ring is well defined" when confronted with two multiplications is silly. You make it sound as if you expect there is some absolute multiplication that rules them all. It only makes sense to doubt whether or not a particular multiplication is well-defined.

Comment: Multiplication in a quotient ring has nothing to do with the setwise product. Quotient ring multiplication is saying that if you multiply any two elements of $I + a$ and $I + b$, you get an element of $I + ab$, which is why the quotient map is well-defined and a homomorphism. It need not be possible to write every element of $I + ab$ as the product of two elements in $I + a$ and $I + b$, in which case the setwise product would give the same answer.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the proof of the fundamental homomorphism theorem for groups, which is more illuminating than the one for rings since it shows why the normality condition is necessary.

Comment: For any $r\in a+I$ and $s\in b+I$ it is a straightforward exercise to show that $rs\in ab+I$ using the fact that $r=a+i$, $s=b+j$ for some $i,j\in I$ and the absorption property of multiplication by an element of an ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The importance of ideals comes from the fact that they're the kernels of a ring homomorphism as consequence of the [first isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_A_(rings)). From perspective if I have a ring homomorphism $\varphi : R \rightarrow Q$ then we can interpret the cosets as the preimages of singletons, ie $\varphi^{-1}(q)$ for $q \in Q$, which is $q + I$ in the usual quotient construction.

This gives us the motivation to define the multiplication of ideals in a way that respects this construction. So by $(q + I)(p + I)$ we mean there exist $r,s \in R$
with $\varphi(r)=q$ and $\varphi(s)=q$ and we are interested in the preimage $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(r)\varphi(s))=\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(rs))$ which is $(qp+I)$.

This is why multiplication of cosets is *not* defined setwise. Even simple ideas like $(2) \subset \mathbb{Z}$ cause trouble immediately since $(2)(2)$ which should simply be $(2)$ since it's $0\cdot 0$ but setwise it would be $(4)$, which as you noted isn't even a coset.

Answer (score 0):

An Excellent Question! I am also troubled by this question for a long time. The key point here is to remember why we define the product on the quotient ring this way. You may think this is a set equation, however what really matters is that we can verify the product is well-defined. In another word, it is independent of the choice of the representation element. You can check the definition of quotient group, you will find out the definition there is actually a set equation (What a bad coincidence, which may make you think the set equation is the crucial thing). But if you check a textbook instead of just a definition, you will find out the reason why we define a normal subgroup is to keep the product well-defined!

Comment: Welcome, Yanyu Wang. I don't think this answers the question. The aim of the quotient ring isn't just to get a "well defined product". That doesn't say much about its ring structure, only that it has one.

Comment: Well, you can consider the case when $I$ is a left ideal instead of a two-sided ideal, then you will find out that you can just prove that $R\I$ is a left $R$ module instead of a ring, in fact, you can verify that (a+I)(b+I)=(ab+I) is not well-defined right now. So the ring structure itself is actually interesting enough, In many cases, you can't even get a ring structure.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you mean that you are considering cosets of an ideal $I$ in a ring $R$, then $$(a+I)(b+I) = ab +aI+bI +I*I = ab + I + I + I= ab + I$$. Because $aI = I$, $I*I = I$ and $I + I=I$ as consequences of the definition of an ideal.

Comment: $I\cdot I = I$ is usually not true.  For example, $(2)\cdot (2) = (4)$.

Comment: You do not multiply ideals together in the product of cosets in a quotient ring! The reason why it's well defined is that the product of any two elements in $I + a$ and $I + b$ is in $I + ab$. That's the whole reason why we can define the product of $I +a$ and $I + b$ to be $I + ab$ and have the quotient map be a homomorphism. There is absolutely no multiplication of ideals going on here.

Comment: @Slade OK, I shoud have written $I\cdot I \subseteq I $, or better used representatives $i_a, i_b \in I$ so that $i_ai_b \in I$